# Variable does not update when it is passed to into a function in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am building multilingual forms. When a user presses a tab a **lang** variable changes. But it is undefined or has an initial value when it is passed to **useFormCRUD** hook. I am coming from React background, so I need your help. I tried to wrap useFormCRUD with watcher but it throws an error.

```
<a-tabs :default-active-key="ContentLanguage.kk" @change="selectTab">
<a-tab-pane :key="ContentLanguage.kk" :tab="$t('common.inKazakh')"></a-tab-pane>
<a-tab-pane :key="ContentLanguage.ru" :tab="$t('common.inRussian')">
</a-row></a-spin>
</div></a-tab-pane>
</a-tabs>

export default {
      name: 'Template',
      setup() {
        let lang = ref(ContentLanguage.kk)
        const {
          isUpdateMode,
          queryParams: { id },
        } = useDetectIsUpdateMode()
    
        const selectTab = (tab) => {
          lang.value = tab
        }
    
        const onGetTemplateById = async () => {
          const { result } = await getTemplateById(id, lang.value ?? 'kk-KK')
          Object.assign(formState, result)
        }
    
        watch(lang, () => {
          onGetTemplateById()
        })
    
        const { formState, initialize, isFetching, onSubmit } = useFormCRUD({
          form: constForm,
          read: onGetTemplateById,
          update: updateTemplate,
          create: createTemplate,
          id,
          isUpdateMode,
          lang: lang.value,
        })
    
        console.log('183', lang.value)
    
        onMounted(() => initialize())
    
        return {
          formState,
          isFetching,
          formatDate,
          isUpdateMode,
          onSubmit,
          selectTab,
          ContentLanguage,
        }
      },
    }
```

Comment: It's unknown how selectTab is used. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Considering that lang value comes from there, you can be pretty sure that a wrong value was provided

Comment: @EstusFlask
Selecting a language works fine. I have added some portion of html, where you can see a listener "selectTab", that is responsible for switching languages

Comment: I see. I missed the point about useFormCRUD. You have to pass the entire lang ref there, not lang.value. It would be the same for React hooks.

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: @EstusFlask
it works, can you post your answer, so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: @EstusFlask
I wonder why is it necessary to pass the whole object ?